# 13.04 Installation not recognising current OS

Tags: 13.04

I have tried installing but the default option is replace current OS with Ubuntu.
There is no option to run alongside.

I have Vista.

The main 13.04 FAQ and help thread is no help in this issue with installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens sometimes, long story short, you're up for some fun with partitioning your hard disk.

If you're not highly technical, an ok compromise is to install Ubuntu using "WUBI". 
What that will do is install Ubuntu to a file on your Windows partition. So you won't have to do any repartitioning.

There are instructions here:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows
It doesn't work with Ubuntu 13.04 unfortunately :o\

Otherwise:
You will need to rearrange your partitions to make space for an EXT4 partition which you will install Ubuntu on. Also you need to leave some space for a 1-2GB 'swap' partition.

But I think you'll find that if you're not already experienced in doing this, that you'll end up accidentally wiping your Windows Vista partition, and you'll loose all your data...

Normally I'd highly recommend Ubuntu 13.04 over 12.04, as there are some really nice changes, but unless you know what you're doing with your partitioning or know someone who can help you do it, I'd advise against it.

If you know someone technical who might be willing to help you I'd recommend getting them to use Team Viewer to log onto your computer remotely via the internet. They can then do whatever is necessary to get your partitions set up correctly.

http://www.teamviewer.com

Either way, I'd recommend you make a backup of your data, as computers have a way of loosing everything you have stored on them when you least expect it.
A computer can retain you're data for a decade without you ever loosing anything, but one day, something will go awry and in a flash everything you worked on is gone. Partitioning is one of the times that's most likely to happen, even when you know completely what you're doing.